# Could NOT find PythonLibs (asking for 3.3 but I have 2.7.6)

Tags: python, c++, cmake, homebrew

I'm working on trying to build the Age of Empires Clone that just got out, to start writing code for it. HOWEVER, I keep getting this error when trying to run configure:

`CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "2.7.6", but required
  is at least "3.3" (found PYTHON_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:341 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:197 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cpp/CMakeLists.txt:74 (find_package)`

The command I ran before I got the error is this:

```
./configure --mode=debug --cpp-compiler=clang++
```

And here's also the link to building.md for actually building the openage project: https://github.com/SFTtech/openage/blob/master/building.md

Answer (score 1):

You may have to download and install Python3 with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3
```

For me it worked after I installed python3 and the listed libaries from https://github.com/SFTtech/openage/blob/master/doc/building.md

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 is many years old already (though still widely used), but version 3.4 at least is out already. Upgrade Python (or install a newer version in parallel) and don't forget the according "-dev" packages that provide the required headers and libs.